# Fetching nid in drupal

Tags: php, drupal-7

Here I want to fetch the nid of matching child term id from my content type product_categories. I used the below code.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node');
$query->entityCondition('bundle', 'product_categories');
$query->propertyCondition('status', 1);
$query->fieldCondition('field_product_sub_cat', 'tid', $child->tid, '=');
$result = $query->execute();
```

I execute the above query and it displays correct results.But now I want to fetch the nid, I used below code but its not working.

```
$childnid = $result->nid; //Area to explore
//print "<pre>"; print_r ((int)$childnid);
print $childnid;
```

can anybody please help me ??

Comment: You need to select the `nid` in the query if you want to use it. Currently you're only selecting `entity_type` & `node`.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. After executing the query, the resulting entity IDs are stored as an array, which is itself inside an array keyed by the entity type (in this case, 'node'). To check for, and get an array of node ID(s), use this directly after you called execute():

```
if (isset($result['node'])) {
  $nids = array_keys($result['node']);
}
```

Adapted from [How to use EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708)